# Why does Mono's CoreCLR blocks internal method reflection from transparent code

Tags: reflection, mono

I'm checking that code, at https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mono/metadata/security-core-clr.c.

If to "ensure that the specified method can be used with reflection since Transparent code cannot call Critical methods" is fine with me, why does CoreCLR also prevents transparent code to call internal transparent methods or properties through reflection ?!

More details about CoreCLR : http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight2CoreCLR .

```
/*
 * mono_security_core_clr_ensure_reflection_access_method:
 *
 *  Ensure that the specified method can be used with reflection since
 *  Transparent code cannot call Critical methods and can only call them
 *  if they are visible from it's point of view.
 *
 *  A MethodAccessException is thrown if the field is cannot be accessed.
 */
void
mono_security_core_clr_ensure_reflection_access_method (MonoMethod *method)
{
    MonoMethod *caller = get_reflection_caller ();
    /* CoreCLR restrictions applies to Transparent code/caller */
    if (mono_security_core_clr_method_level (caller, TRUE) != MONO_SECURITY_CORE_CLR_TRANSPARENT)
        return;

    if (mono_security_core_clr_get_options () & MONO_SECURITY_CORE_CLR_OPTIONS_RELAX_REFLECTION) {
        if (!mono_security_core_clr_is_platform_image (method->klass->image))
            return;
    }

    /* Transparent code cannot invoke, even using reflection, Critical code */
    if (mono_security_core_clr_method_level (method, TRUE) == MONO_SECURITY_CORE_CLR_CRITICAL) {
        mono_raise_exception (get_method_access_exception (
            "Transparent method %s cannot invoke Critical method %s.", 
            caller, method));
    }

    /* also it cannot invoke a method that is not visible from it's (caller) point of view */
    if (!check_method_access (caller, method)) {
        mono_raise_exception (get_method_access_exception (
            "Transparent method %s cannot invoke private/internal method %s.", 
            caller, method));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you're asking the wrong question: why should CoreCLR allow transparent code to call internal methods? Tt doesn't matter if they're transparent or not, there's a reason a method is internal and you can make the object confused if internal methods are called directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on mono-project's discussion list :

> In Silverlight, reflection is as powerful as statically compiled 
>   code. With other words, if the code does not compile due to member 
>   access violations, then reflection won't help either.
>
> While this rule doesn't add concrete security, it helps obscuring 
>   stuff from application code w/out having to decorate members with 
>   [SecurityCritical].

http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Why-does-Mono-s-CoreCLR-blocks-internal-method-reflection-from-transparent-code-tt4659140.html;cid=1367365433900-162